# Can a boost::mpl::list be too long?

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

My application requires that 100 - 200 event handler classes be instantiated (and registered) for *each* device that our codebase supports. My idea is to place these handlers in a list like so

```
typedef mpl::list<
            HandlerFoo,
            HandlerBar,
            TypedHandler<char> ,
            TypedHandler<bool>
            ...         // lots more
            > EventHandlers;
```

and then use `boost::mpl::for_each<EventHandlers>` to iterate through the list of handlers and instantiate each type. The problem is that, as I said, I may have to list up to 200. Is this a excessive use of `boost::mpl::list` or is there a more suitable alternative?

Comment: Try a C++11 variadic template. If you can't use C++11, try nested `mpl::list`s (about 20 lists of 10 elements each should work).

Comment: By C++03 standards it would be excessive, but modern compilers are more tolerant.

Comment: @MSalters compilers are, boost::mpl::list is (by default) not. It accepts 20 parameters and you need to jump through hoops to change that.